# how to mock an instance method invocation from static method while writing junit for static method?

Tags: junit, mockito, powermockito

how to mock an instance method invocation from static method while writing junit for static method?I'm writing tests for existing code.

```
class A
{
   public static D methodX()
   {
      B b = new B();
      C c = b.doSomething();
   }
}

class B
{
   public C doSomething()
   {
     return C;
   }
}

class Atest
{
    @Test
    public void testMethodX()
    {
       B b =Mockito.mock(B.class);
       Mockito.when(b.doSomething()).thenReturn(new C());
       A.methodX();
       // some assertions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your tag selection you already know that you need to go for PowerMockito.

In order to inject a mocked version of B class i would do the following:

**A class**

```
class A
{
   public static D methodX()
   {
      B b = getBInstance();
      C c = b.doSomething();
   }

   static B getBInstance(){
      return new B();
   }

}
```

**Test Class**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
class Atest
{
    @Test
    public void testMethodX()
    {
       B b =Mockito.mock(B.class);
       PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(A.class, "getBInstance")).toReturn(b);
       Mockito.when(b.doSomething()).thenReturn(new C());
       A.methodX();
       // some assertions
    }
}
```

Thanks to `PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method` call you will just mock the `getBInstance` static method and in the end call the real `A.methodX` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Another completely different approach: do **not** write un-testable code. **static** is an abnormality within good OO designs; to the first step is to simply **not** write **static** methods.

And when you have good reasons to still do so; then write them in a way that allows you reasonable unit-test them.

Yes, it is possible to turn to PowerMock(ito) to get this solved, but the more *sane* approach is to simple fix your production design.

The PowerMock(ito) frameworks come at certain cost; and can **easily** be avoided.

Thus, my answer: learn how to create *testable* code; and simply forget about PowerMock (you can start by watching these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79)).